# Can't change KDE Kickoff menu style

Tags: 15.04, kubuntu, kde

I attempted to change the Kickoff menu style in Kubuntu 15.04 by right clicking on the icon and then "Alternatives", and then changing to "Application Menu". That worked, but now I am not able to switch back.

When I attempt to do the same thing to switch back, the Alternatives menu does not seem to work properly. "Application Launcher" is marked as selected even though it is not the option used, and I can't click any button other than cancel so I can't switch back.

I've tried to find some config file to edit this manually but I've been unsuccessful.

Any ideas?

[The menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipBw3.png)

Answer (score 0):

Was able to solve the problem by upgrading to the latest version of plasma using:

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports
>
> sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade